# PickerView - open the last selected row

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I have 2 pickerViews. One of them has his own customPickerViewClass and both aren't in the ViewController.
I've done it to make them talk with the ViewController.
But what I want to do now is, when a row was selected and the title saved in a variable, how can I make it select this row automatically when opening the pickerView again?

Comment: Please show some sample code, when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you save a `variable` with the `selected value` you can do the following:

```
if let index = array.index(where: { $0 == variable }) {
    picker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}
```

You search for the index in your `array` source which you use to populate your `picker`, then you find the the index by searching for the `variable` which is the one you have saved. Then you select that row in your  `picker`.

Comment: Either where you load the view or whenever you want to load the `picker` with that value.

Comment: Okay, thank you but I have another question. In my case, the pickerVies are related to each other.

So, if selectedRow = 0 the other pickerView will show other rows in contrast to when selectedRow = 1 

The problem here is that, if I select a row outside the original didSelectRow function for pickerViews, it just select them on the UI but don't really recognize a true selection

How can I fix that?

Comment: This is how I managed the relation between the 2 pickerViews

https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/33279460/ScreenShot2017-06-04at15.03.01.png

Comment: I don´t really get it. Do you mean that if you select a row in pickerView 1 and if that row is outside the range of pickerView 2 then you don´t know what to do?

Comment: No, if I a select a row with pickerView.selectRow(...).
The pickerView selects the row only on UI but doesn't detect a real selection

Comment: By real selection you mean in the array or?

Comment: Yes. I have a label for each pickerView a label that gets the text of the selected Row and by selecting a row with pickerView.selectRow, the labels doesn't get the text so the selection happens only on UI

Comment: Well in the `if let index` you do also have to set all your labels etc. If you an array with all your data just use the `index` to get right data index and populate everything.

Comment: Np glad to help. Good luck with your project.